# Maximum clock frequency on DE1-SOC

Tags: verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

What is the maximum clock frequency that can be generated with Altera PLLs in DE1-SOC board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a reference to a maximum PLL frequency in any of the Cyclone V documentation. However, it appears (from my own experimentation) that the *Altera PLL* megafunction/IP Core won't product a generated clock with a frequency faster than 1.6 GHz (1600 MHz).

That said, I doubt you'll be able to clock any CV circuitry (even fully pipelined) that quickly.